# error while binding datatable to reportviewer table

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, reportviewer

I have filled datatable. I want to display it in the report. I'm doing like this:

```
ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("dtss", dt);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
ReportViewer1.DataBind();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

But when i try to build, i get error:

> The dataset ‘DataSet1’ refers to the data source “”, which does not exist.

What am I missing? Using Webforms(ASP.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name that you give your ReportDataSource needs to match the name of the DataSet (defined within the report).  For example, on line 1 (of your code, above) you need to say:

```
ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
```

or rename the dataset (in your report) to "dtss"

Comment: no result, maybe something else missing? I have created table in report. Assiged DataSetName to dtss. And still have the same error. Maybe i should bind data source somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative.

Apparently if you add a DataSet within the rdlc file it auto associates the name in the xml, and when you delete that from the rdlc it doesn’t remove it from the xml, so it just gives you a reference which it thinks of as an empty dataset, and cannot evaluate. I first named my second one DataSet2 and then after setting it up in the design decided to delete it and rename it, but you have to go back to the xml and delete the entire empty DataSet node<>.
Hope this helps someone who's problems cannot be solved by the above answer.